# memory issue of copying C++ vectors

Tags: c++, memory

I somehow fixed a memory issue in my code but am not quite sure what actually happens and I would like to see if anyone could possibly give me a reasonable explanation.

The code involves doing some computation with a class `ANN_Force`, initially when setting up parameter `values_of_biased_nodes`, I use following code:

```
values_of_biased_nodes = bias;
```

and that gives me following memory error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__memmove_avx_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-avx-unaligned.S:138
138 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-avx-unaligned.S: No such file 
or directory.

#0  __memmove_avx_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-avx-unaligned.S:138
#1  0x00007ffff7a0c903 in std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >::operator=(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > const&) () from /home/kengyangyao/.openmm/lib/libOpenMM.so
#2  0x00007ffff7a5bdcf in std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > >::operator=(std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > > const&) () from /home/kengyangyao/.openmm/lib/libOpenMM.so
#3  0x00007ffff76a3122 in OpenMM::ANN_Force::set_values_of_biased_nodes (this=0x6480e0, bias=...)
at /home/kengyangyao/Dropbox/temp_Linux/ANN_Force/openmmapi/src/ANN_Force.cpp:57
#4  0x000000000040cd4a in test_forward_and_backward_prop () at test_ANN_package.cpp:110
#5  0x000000000041468b in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdae8) at test_ANN_package.cpp:598
```

When I added a line:

```
values_of_biased_nodes.resize(bias.size());
values_of_biased_nodes = bias;
```

The problem disappeared but I have no idea why.  My guess would be without `resize`, `values_of_biased_nodes = bias;` simply moves whatever in `bias` directly to `values_of_biased_nodes` without checking if the memory near `values_of_biased_nodes` is large enough to hold the values.  I wonder if anyone could help me figure it out?  Also I noticed that in some machines it works without `resize`, is it due to different memory management strategies, or simply because those machines have large enough memory?

Thank you!

UPDATED: I ran it with valgrind, here is output:

```
==13494== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==13494== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==13494== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==13494== Command: ./test_ANN_package
==13494== 
/home/kengyangyao/.openmm/lib/plugins
running test_forward_and_backward_prop
==13494== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==13494==    at 0x4F9689E: std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >::operator=(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > const&) (in /home/kengyangyao/.openmm/lib/libOpenMM.so)
==13494==    by 0x4FE5DCE: std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > >::operator=(std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > > const&) (in /home/kengyangyao/.openmm/lib/libOpenMM.so)
==13494==    by 0x5374121: OpenMM::ANN_Force::set_values_of_biased_nodes(std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > >) (ANN_Force.cpp:57)
==13494==    by 0x40CD49: test_forward_and_backward_prop() (test_ANN_package.cpp:110)
==13494==    by 0x41468A: main (test_ANN_package.cpp:598)
==13494==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==13494==    at 0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==13494==    by 0x41BACF: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:104)
==13494==    by 0x41ACA5: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::allocate(std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:491)
==13494==    by 0x419809: std::_Vector_base<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:170)
==13494==    by 0x41904A: std::_Vector_base<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::_M_create_storage(unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:185)
==13494==    by 0x41728C: std::_Vector_base<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::_Vector_base(unsigned long, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > const&) (stl_vector.h:136)
==13494==    by 0x4155AB: std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::vector(unsigned long, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > const&) (stl_vector.h:278)
==13494==    by 0x415072: OpenMM::ANN_Force::ANN_Force() (in /home/kengyangyao/Dropbox/temp_Linux/ANN_Force/openmmapi/tests/test_ANN_package)
==13494==    by 0x40C8AA: test_forward_and_backward_prop() (test_ANN_package.cpp:103)
==13494==    by 0x41468A: main (test_ANN_package.cpp:598)
==13494== 
==13494== Invalid write of size 1
==13494==    at 0x4C3245C: memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==13494==    by 0x4F96902: std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >::operator=(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > const&) (in /home/kengyangyao/.openmm/lib/libOpenMM.so)
==13494==    by 0x4FE5DCE: std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > >::operator=(std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > > const&) (in /home/kengyangyao/.openmm/lib/libOpenMM.so)
==13494==    by 0x5374121: OpenMM::ANN_Force::set_values_of_biased_nodes(std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > >) (ANN_Force.cpp:57)
==13494==    by 0x40CD49: test_forward_and_backward_prop() (test_ANN_package.cpp:110)
==13494==    by 0x41468A: main (test_ANN_package.cpp:598)
==13494==  Address 0x3f947ae147ae147b is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==13494== 
==13494== 
==13494== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==13494==  General Protection Fault
==13494==    at 0x4C3245C: memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==13494==    by 0x4F96902: std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >::operator=(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > const&) (in /home/kengyangyao/.openmm/lib/libOpenMM.so)
==13494==    by 0x4FE5DCE: std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > >::operator=(std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > > const&) (in /home/kengyangyao/.openmm/lib/libOpenMM.so)
==13494==    by 0x5374121: OpenMM::ANN_Force::set_values_of_biased_nodes(std::vector<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, std::allocator<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > >) (ANN_Force.cpp:57)
==13494==    by 0x40CD49: test_forward_and_backward_prop() (test_ANN_package.cpp:110)
==13494==    by 0x41468A: main (test_ANN_package.cpp:598)
==13494== 
==13494== HEAP SUMMARY:
==13494==     in use at exit: 2,016,954 bytes in 7,600 blocks
==13494==   total heap usage: 9,419 allocs, 1,819 frees, 2,218,864 bytes allocated
==13494== 
==13494== LEAK SUMMARY:
==13494==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13494==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13494==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13494==    still reachable: 2,016,954 bytes in 7,600 blocks
==13494==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==13494==                         stdstring          : 196 bytes in 6 blocks
==13494==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13494== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==13494== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==13494== 
==13494== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==13494== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
[1]    13494 segmentation fault (core dumped)  valgrind --leak-check=yes --track-origins=yes ./test_ANN_package
```

seems that some memory is not correctly handled?

Comment: Show us a [mcve], please.

Comment: My magic crystal ball says your code has undefined behavior.

Comment: Are both values_of_biased_nodes and bias vectors of the same type?

Comment: I don't think that's the full error message as it doesn't say _what_ the error is, it only says _where_ it originates.

Comment: @FredLarson I cannot come up with good MCV example for now, since it depends on many other packages.

Comment: @user657267 What does "undefined behavior" specifically mean here?

Comment: Also, try compiling with `-Wall -Wextra` for starters and fixing any warnings you get. Then try compiling with address sanitizer enabled (Google it up).

Comment: @JimPri Yes, they are of the same type, but size of values_of_biased_nodes is undetermined at the beginning.

Comment: The size of an uninitialized vector is not undefined if you are using the standard library implementation: the size is zero, with some amount of memory preallocated.

Comment: Well, it looks like *"Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)"*, with line number too. I suggest you fix that first... Then turn on those warnings, they would probably (not always, which why tools like *valgrind* are a nice thing to have too) have told you this already!

Comment: @user3326682 Probably memory corruption, you're probably writing somewhere you shouldn't be but without the code it's impossible to say.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning one vector to another does not require that you resize the target vector before performing the assignment; that would be a terrible design. I suspect you have other memory issues in play and this just reveals them. Have you tried running this under valgrind?

---

After looking at your valgrind output, it's clear that you have memory corruption but it's difficult to say exactly what's going on without seeing the offending lines of source code. I recommend running under gdb and breaking on the line that generates the first valgrind error. If you can figure the problem out on your own, then fix it and rerun it under valgrind, repeating as necessary until you fix all the errors. If you cannot figure out the problem, please post the offending lines +- 10 lines and I'll take a look.

Comment: I just ran it under valgrind and updated the post, seems there is some problem with handling memory.

Comment: Hi I just updated valgrind output, it says "Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation", could you take a look at this part and tell me what it mean here? Thanks!

Comment: I cannot help you just by seeing the valgrind output. Also you will want to tackle these errors in order because you don't know if the first error is causing the second one. It looks to me like the first error is coming from here: ANN_Force.cpp:57

Comment: "ANN_Force.cpp:57" this line is exactly `values_of_biased_nodes = bias;`.  I have another hypothesis: I noticed before this line, I may do something inappropriate.  Does the each `vector<double>` in `vector<vector<double> >` have to have exactly same size?

Comment: There is nothing that guarantees that each sub-vector in a vector has the same size.